# iOS The system bluetooth failed to connect with the device

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, ancs

We have developed a smart wearable device by ourselves. Until last month, when the device leaves the Bluetooth connection range of the iPhone system and then returns to the range again, the system Bluetooth can successfully connect with the device automatically. But a few days ago, a customer’s mobile phone left the device After 1 hour of connection range, it can't connect back. And when we open the app developed by ourselves, we can't automatically connect back.

I can't figure out where the problem is. How can I locate the problem? Or can anyone tell me what is the reason for this phenomenon? Thank you very much

Problematic iPhone Xs Max, iOS 16.0.2

Phenomena about apps

1. The app enters the foreground from the background, I did the following operations

```
NSUUID *uuid = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:reconnectId];
NSArray *retPers = [self.cbcm retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers:@[uuid]];
CBPeripheral *peripheral = [retPers firstObject];
NSDictionary *options = @{CBConnectPeripheralOptionNotifyOnDisconnectionKey : @(YES),CBConnectPeripheralOptionEnableTransportBridgingKey : @(YES)};
[self.cbcm connectPeripheral:peripheral options:options];
```

2. When I restarted my app, I found that it can successfully connect back automatically.

Comment: Normally you would opt-in to Bluetooth state restoration, enable Bluetooth background mode and the when you get a call to the `didDisconnect` delegate method, simply call `connect` again. When the device comes back into range, iOS will connect and notify your delegate, relaunching your app if required.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't seem to solve my problem, when I restart the app is able to connect normally, everything is normal. But when my program is in the background and the peripheral disConnect is more than 1 hour close again, the app from the background When I entered the foreground and tried to connect to the device, the agent did not call back, and the connection was not successful. When I opened the phone settings -> Bluetooth, I found that the connection was not successful here. The probability of this happening on other phones is extremely low.